# Sort specific column and order everything by high number to the low

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, tr

Won't to order column status by high number to lower.

```
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":74,"diskusage":"/home/u0261072"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":74,"diskusage":"/home/u0261072"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":79,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.74","hostname":"qr01036","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.74","hostname":"qr01036","status":8,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.75","hostname":"qr01037","status":1,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.75","hostname":"qr01037","status":34,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.75","hostname":"qr01037","status":74,"diskusage":"/mnt/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.76","hostname":"qr01038","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.76","hostname":"qr01038","status":34,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.77","hostname":"qr01039","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.77","hostname":"qr01039","status":63,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":63,"diskusage":"/staging/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":74,"diskusage":"/mnt/"}
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":81,"diskusage":"/"},
```

I try with

```
sort -t: -k3,3r
```

but without success ....

Expected view:

```
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":81,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":79,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":74,"diskusage":"/home/u0261072"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":74,"diskusage":"/home/u0261072"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.75","hostname":"qr01037","status":74,"diskusage":"/mnt/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":74,"diskusage":"/mnt/"}
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.77","hostname":"qr01039","status":63,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":63,"diskusage":"/staging/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.76","hostname":"qr01038","status":34,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.75","hostname":"qr01037","status":34,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.74","hostname":"qr01036","status":8,"diskusage":"/"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.75","hostname":"qr01037","status":1,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.77","hostname":"qr01039","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.76","hostname":"qr01038","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.74","hostname":"qr01036","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.72","hostname":"qr01034","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.78","hostname":"qr01040","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
sort -t: -k4,4rn
```

The `n` modifier means to sort numerically instead of lexicographically. And the status number is field 4, not 3. Here are the fields:

```
{"ipaddr":"10.1.2.74","hostname":"qr01036","status":0,"diskusage":"/dev/shm"},
<---1---> <---------2----------> <-------3--------> <-----4-----> <----5----->
```

Comment: Yeah it works but tell me why exactly 4, I'm little confuse ?

Comment: @KalinBorisov: Count the columns agains delimited by `:`. `81,"diskusage"` is indeed at # 4.

Comment: I added a diagram of the field numbers.

Comment: @Barmar How to order non-numeric column, for example to have state like `running`, `stopping, `noexec` and etc and everything to be ordered by all columns with running to be on top or in the middle, all noexec to be after it and so long ...

Comment: You can't do that with `sort` by itself. You could preprocess the data with something like `awk`, adding a numeric column corresponding to the state, and then sort by that.